# Trouble talking to web service in C#: XmlChoiceIdentifierATtribute is not valid in Items

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

There is a [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) webservice that is out of my control that I'm having trouble with; I can interact with this service using [soapUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoapUI) and using Add Service Reference -> advanced -> Add Web Reference without a problem.

However, when I attempt to talk to it using the standard Add Service Reference method (add a service reference, connect using the generated code from wsdl.exe), I get the following error:

> XmlSerializer attribute System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute is not 
>       valid in Items. Only XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute and 
>       XmlAnyElement attributes are supported when IsWrapped is true.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web 
>       request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where 
>       it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: XmlSerializer attribute 
>       System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute is not valid in Items. Only 
>       XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute and XmlAnyElement attributes are
>       supported when IsWrapped is true.

I've read some things saying there is some SOAP incompatibility between Java and .NET, but searching around I can find virtually no one who is having this problem, making me think I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: SOAP is not an issue here because you haven't started producing/consuming messages yet. There are SOAP extensions to WSDL, but what you have is an issue with svcutil.exe properly generating a service proxy based on the data contracts in the WSDL.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? Are you trying to consume the Services with WCF? What platform is your client running (it is important to know if you are using Silverlight or Compact framework).

Comment: .Net 4.0 / MVC 3.0 / I'm not doing anything fancy. This is a blank 3.0 MVC template and all I've done is Add service reference. So I'm guessing Compact.

Comment: This does appear to be a bug in how the WCF client generation code is creating proxy classes, using the XmlSerializer, to access this service. You've already found the workaround ("Add Web Reference"), but if you ever want this fixed, you should submit a bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/. If you don't want to do it yourself, and if you can post a link to the WSDL, I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that the `DataContractSerializer` (default for WCF) cannot handle the schema (this is typical in non WCF-WCF scenarios) so it "falls back" and generates a proxy which uses `XmlSerializer`. It is possible that the "fallback" mechanism of generating a proxy for use with `XmlSerializer` is not generating it in a manner consistent with that of the direct-to-XmlSerializer approach used by Add Web reference.

When you Go to "Advanced->Add Web Reference" you are manually telling Visual Studio to use a meechanism that directly generates proxies which use the `XmlSerializer` instead of using the fallback mechanism.

Comment: @Doug - What are you trying to fix? It works when you use `Add Web Reference`. Do you have a specific need to generate a `DataContractSerializer` proxy?

Comment: -1: not accurate. It is generating an XmlSerializer proxy because the schema doesn't fit the parameters of DataContractSerializer. Clearly, it uses `<xs:choice/>`, and that won't work with the `DataContractSerializer`. The only question is why "Add Service Reference", when it falls back to the `XmlSerializer` can't handle this, but just plain "Add Web Reference" can. It's an unusual reversal - it usually happens the other way around.

Comment: @John - How is this not accurate? Your comment matches what I said in my response. I believe my response "DataContractSerializer ... cannot handle the schema" is the same as your comment "the schema doesn't fit the parameters of DataContractSerializer". Additionally, an XmlSerializer proxy is **not** being generated in this specific case (proxy generation fails). By using Add Web Reference the OP can directly have an XmlSerializer proxy generated.

Comment: @Ethan: for one thing, you're confusing the proxy technology with the serialization technology. "Add Service Reference" is generating a WCF proxy which uses the [`[XmlSerializerFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) attribute to force use of the XML Serializer. Apparently, it does so in a manner that doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @John - you are right in that I didn't see that communication was failing, I thought that the actual "Add Service reference" was failing. I will change my post when my eye's are not as blurry. Nevertheless, the end result of the post (i.e. "Just use Add Web reference") is a valid suggestion. Donwvotes are for Non-Useful answers. Comments and Edits are the appropriate first-courses of action for "salvageable" posts (but you have been here longer than I have, so do as you please).

Comment: @Ethan: I do what I please regardless. If you fix your post, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Re: fixing it. Adding a web reference does indeed resolve the issue, but the code generated by wsdl.exe vs the code from svutil.exe are rather different. So, for consistency within the project I'm stuck either using all (add web reference) or (add service reference). I'd prefer the latter because it's newer, and the api it creates is better (opinion). Isn't there a way to force XmlSerializer to be used in the web.config options?

Comment: @John - fixed it even with blurry eyes since I don't want you to hate me :)

Comment: OK. Your response sounds good, Ethan.
But, how to resolve it.