# accessing java service from C#; XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute is not valid in Items error

Tags: c#, java, service

I have to access an external service which is not under my control. So I add a service reference via vs2012 and everything is fine.

I can check the behaviour of the service via soapUI. So all looks ok.

But after initializing the client as below, I notice client.InnerChannel and other properties are mostly in error. (Some properties have errors as the one below, some saying the service is in faulted state)

```
SomeService.SomeServiceV1x1Client client = new SomeService.SomeServiceV1x1Client ();
```

If I proceed to use **client.InnerChannel** I get the following error:

```
XmlSerializer attribute System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute is not valid in Items. 
Only XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute and XmlAnyElement attributes are supported when IsWrapped is true.
```

**Short Version:**

Is there some common incompatilibity issue with  elements in wsdl affecting the reference.cs causing this type of behaviour? More importantly, is there a decent workaround rather than...the one below. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185162/trouble-talking-to-web-service-in-c-xmlchoiceidentifierattribute-is-not-valid) the problem is explained (more or less) but doesn't help alot in this case.

**Long Version:**

Checking the wsdl, there is a part such as this:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="getCitizenFromLocalDb">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="citizenId" type="profileMgmnt:IdType" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="surname" type="xsd:string" /> >
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="birthDate" type="xsd:date" /> 
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Checking the References.cs,

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://somwhere.com/SomeService/Service/V4", IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType {

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":birthDate")]
    birthDate,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":citizenId")]
    citizenId,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":name")]
    name,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":surname")]
    surname,
}

public partial class getCitizenFromLocalDbRequest {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("birthDate", typeof(System.DateTime), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="date")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("citizenId", typeof(long), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("name", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("surname", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public object[] Items;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://somewhere.com/SomeService/Service/V4", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public GeneralServices.SomeService.ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName;

    public getCitizenFromLocalDbRequest() {
    }

    public getCitizenFromLocalDbDbRequest(object[] Items, GeneralServices.SomeService.ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName) {
        this.Items = Items;
        this.ItemsElementName = ItemsElementName;
    }
}
```

---

Now to solve this, I changed the getCitizenFromLocalDbRequest as below and also removed ItemsChoiceType enum from the references.cs. Is there some common incompatilibity issue causing this type of behaviour? More importantly, is there a decent workaround rather than...this?

```
public partial class getCitizenFromLocalDbRequest {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://somewhere.com/SomeService/Service/V4", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public long citizenId;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://somewhere.com/SomeService/Service/V4", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string name;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://somewhere.com/SomeService/Service/V4", Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string surname;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://somewhere.com/SomeService/Service/V4", Order=3)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="date")]
    public System.DateTime birthDate;


    public getCitizenFromLocalDbRequest() {
    }

    public getCitizenFromLocalDbRequest(long citizenId, string name, string surname,  System.DateTime birthDate) {
        this.citizenId = citizenId;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you come to any conclusions with this? I have the same issue, but I have hundreds of auto generated types that I don't want to manually edit